# Azure blob storage - findBlobsByTags always fails with error Error parsing query at or near character position 1: unexpected &apos;1&apos;

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am using Azure Blob storage. While persisting blobs, I have persisted index tags. I am able to see index tags when I download the blobs through Microsoft Azure storage explorer.
Programatically, I am trying to filter the tags(using azure-storage-blob version **12.15.0**)

I am using this api to get details from DB - **findBlobsByTags**

This is the code I am trying

```
    FindBlobsOptions findByTags = new FindBlobsOptions(searchExpression));
    findByTags.setMaxResultsPerPage(100);
    PagedIterable<TaggedBlobItem> blobsByTags = blobContainerClient.findBlobsByTags(findByTags, Duration.ofSeconds(30), Context.NONE);
```

I have tried following queries

```
 1.   String searchExpression = "where=@container = 'container-name' AND \"field\" = \'value\'";
 2. String searchExpression = "where=field=value";
 3. String searchExpression = "where=\"field\" =\'value\'";
     String escapeJava = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(searchExpression);
 4. String searchExpression = "&where=\"trackingId\"=\'TA00965650\'";
```

and I am getting this exception.

> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 400, "
>
> `InvalidQueryParameterValue`**Error parsing
> query at or near character position 1: unexpected '1'**
> RequestId:78043a6d-901e-00de-0797-510acf000000
> Time:2022-04-16T13:42:00.7475672Zwherewhere="field"='value'This query parameter value is invalid."] with root cause
> com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 400, "
>
> `InvalidQueryParameterValue`Error parsing
> query at or near character position 1: unexpected '1'
> RequestId:78043a6d-901e-00de-0797-510acf000000
> Time:2022-04-16T13:42:00.7475672Zwherewhere="trackingId"='TA00965650'This
> query parameter value is invalid." at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at
> com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:390)
> at

From the exception log it looks like the query I am passing to the findBlobsByTags method has issues in parsing. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. If some escaping/encoding needs to be done

Comment: Can you try by removing `where=` from your search expression? Do something like `String searchExpression = "field=value";`?

Comment: hi @GauravMantri, yes this worked. Thanks, please add this as answer
The documentation examples mentions `where=` in all of there examples.
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient.findblobsbytags?view=azure-java-stable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, please remove `where=` from your search expression. Documentation seems to be incorrect. You may want to create an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues so that the documentation can be corrected.

You can see working code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-storage-blob_12.16.0/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/test/java/com/azure/storage/blob/ContainerAPITest.groovy.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue. I updated the query as below and it works fine.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = getBlobServiceClient();

PagedIterable<TaggedBlobItem> findBlobsByTags = blobServiceClient.findBlobsByTags("\"Company\"='ABC'");

for(TaggedBlobItem taggedBlobItem : findBlobsByTags) {
    System.out.println("Find Blob, ContainerName - " + taggedBlobItem.getContainerName()+", Name - "+taggedBlobItem.getName());
}
```